# How do I cast/convert an array of objects to generic type T when T is defined as an array?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Given a generic class `Foo<T>` with a method `public T Convert(string value)`, I am trying to handle the possibility that `T` is defined as an array.

For example, `T` as a simple type:

```
Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>();
int bar = foo.Convert("123");
// bar == 123
```

But also, `T` as an array:

```
Foo<int[]> foo = new Foo<int[]>();
int[] bars = foo.Convert("1,2,3");
// bars = [1, 2, 3]
```

Here is class Foo with an invalid cast that I'm not quite sure how to resolve.

```
public class Foo<T>
{

    public T Convert(string value)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (t.IsArray)
        {
            string[] values = value.Split(',');
            Type elementType = t.GetElementType();
            // this cast is invalid
            return (T)values.Select(v => elementType.IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(elementType, v, true) : ChangeType(v, elementType)).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)ChangeType(value, t);
        }
    }

    private object ChangeType(string value, Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return default;
            }
            type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        }
        return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }

}
```

Comment: In the line of invalid cast... Do you need to cast it as `T` or `T[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really using the features of generics here, except getting the type via typeof(T). So a solution without generics would be:

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Convert(string value, Type t)
    {
        if (t.IsArray)
        {
            string[] values = value.Split(',');
            Type elementType = t.GetElementType();
            var array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);
            for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                array.SetValue(elementType.IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(elementType, values[i], true) : ChangeType(values[i], elementType), i);
            }
            return array;
        }
        else
        {
            return ChangeType(value, t);
        }
    }

    private object ChangeType(string value, Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return default;
            }
            type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        }
        return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }
}
```

Note that I use `Array.CreateInstance` to create e.g. a proper `int[]` instead of the `object[]` created by your `values.Select(v => elementType.IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(elementType, v, true) : ChangeType(v, elementType)).ToArray()`.

If you want, you can still have a generic version on top of it:

```
public class Foo<T> : Foo
{
    public T Convert(string value)
    {
        return (T)Convert(value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I was skirting around this all day. I had attempted it with Array.CreateInstance and somehow I just missed that it could be cast as an object and then T. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep your impl that understands `Foo<int>` and use it to make an array:

```
int[] bars = "1,2,3".Split(",").Select(foo.Convert).ToArray();
```

This way the calling method can be the one who knows how the array is arranged rather than baking it into Convert as a CSV:

```
int[] bars = "1-2-3".Split("-").Select(foo.Convert).ToArray();
```

I do wonder what you really gain over swapping foo.Convert out for int.Parse though.. Looks like you're writing a large, confusing, slow mega parser for little gain over offering a static Parse method per your custom type and calling it as per above